# I need a Logic-FULL templating engine

Tags: templating

I'm looking for a templating engine similar to handlebars.js/handlebars.net.  I need to generate formatted text.  The expressions can be quite complex.  Ideally, the library will have native support for queries like `ANY, MAX, MIN` etc (similar to Microsoft LINQ).

The problem with handlebars is it doesn't allow me to do things like

```
{{if( variableName == "abcd")}}
```

Much less Max/Min etc... I need Logic-FULL templates as opposed to handlebars philosophy of Logic-LESS templates.  I get their philosophy and it's great, but I have a specific and narrow need to fill.

The context for the data model will be coming from a .NET core project.  If we have to we could convert that model over to another platform if we need to run under node or something.